# Difference in plugin tutorials: no header file vs yes header file

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Noob here!  I've read through the plugin tutorials, for example

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_model&cat=write_plugin

and also the sensors tutorials, and noticed an apparent difference between how plugins are handled.  In the model plugin tutorial above there's no mention of a header file for the plugin but in the contact sensor tutorial

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=contact_sensor&cat=sensors

there is a plugin shown and it includes a header file.  Can you tell me the reason for the difference?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12332/difference-in-plugin-tutorials:-no-header-file-vs-yes-header-file/) by [raequin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2401/raequin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 165 on 2016-01-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you're familiar with C++, you'll understand that in some cases header files aren't necessary. When you're writing single-file programs, like most gazebo plugins are, then you'll rarely need a header file. Header files just help organize and share code, but they aren't always required.

This is a simple example of "well we could write a header file, or we could be lazy and just not". You certainly don't *need* one for the sensor tutorial, but we thought it wasn't too much extra work. Plus, it's always good practice to write header files, in case your project grows and you want more code. Then it will be helpful, or even required, to have a header file.

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2016-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raequin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2401/raequin/) on 2016-01-15**:
Oh, yeah.  I remember that!  I don't do much programming.  Thanks.